# Using .order invalidates .where conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following method which returns `CourseTypes`, including related `courses`. (The `enrolments` are not important.)

What I just noticed is, that if I add the `.order(:order)` in line 2, every `where` conditional is being ignored. This means `expired` and `cancelled` courses are being included.

When I omit the `.order(:order)`, these (unwanted) courses are not included.

Why is this and how can I order the `CourseTypes` array/activerecord relation correctly, without loosing the filter options?

```
  def course_types
    CourseType.order(:order).
      includes(courses: :enrolments).
      where.not("title LIKE ?" , "%Test%").
      where(courses: {
        expired: false,
        cancelled: false,
      })
  end
```

Thanks!

Update:

**Generated query without `.order(:order)`:**

I've excluded the `.enrolments` in the queries to make the output shorter and I've translated the db field in the query to match the english names I used in the initial question.

SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT "course_types"."id" AS t0_r0, "course_types"."title" AS t0_r1, "course_types"."description" AS t0_r2, "course_types"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "course_types"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "course_types"."order" AS t0_r5, "course_types"."price" AS t0_r6, "course_types"."seats" AS t0_r7, "course_types"."days" AS t0_r8, "course_types"."ue" AS t0_r9, "courses"."id" AS t1_r0, "courses"."titel" AS t1_r1, "courses"."startdate" AS t1_r2, "courses"."enddate" AS t1_r3, "courses"."content" AS t1_r4, "courses"."audience" AS t1_r5, "courses"."time" AS t1_r6, "courses"."scope" AS t1_r7, "courses"."points" AS t1_r8, "courses"."tutor" AS t1_r9, "courses"."place" AS t1_r10, "courses"."active" AS t1_r11, "courses"."created_at" AS t1_r12, "courses"."updated_at" AS t1_r13, "courses"."category" AS t1_r14, "courses"."expired" AS t1_r15, "courses"."price" AS t1_r16, "courses"."cancelled" AS t1_r17, "courses"."notes" AS t1_r18, "courses"."url" AS t1_r19, "courses"."course_type_id" AS t1_r20 FROM "course_types" LEFT OUTER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."course_type_id" = "course_types"."id" WHERE (NOT (title LIKE '%Test%')) AND "courses"."active" = $1 AND "courses"."expired" = $2 AND "courses"."cancelled" = $3  [["active", "t"], ["expired", "f"], ["cancelled", "f"]]

**Generated query with `.oder(:order)`**:

SQL (1.0ms)  SELECT "course_types"."id" AS t0_r0, "course_types"."title" AS t0_r1, "course_types"."description" AS t0_r2, "course_types"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "course_types"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "course_types"."order" AS t0_r5, "course_types"."price" AS t0_r6, "course_types"."seats" AS t0_r7, "course_types"."days" AS t0_r8, "course_types"."ue" AS t0_r9, "courses"."id" AS t1_r0, "courses"."titel" AS t1_r1, "courses"."startdate" AS t1_r2, "courses"."enddate" AS t1_r3, "courses"."content" AS t1_r4, "courses"."audience" AS t1_r5, "courses"."time" AS t1_r6, "courses"."scope" AS t1_r7, "courses"."points" AS t1_r8, "courses"."tutor" AS t1_r9, "courses"."place" AS t1_r10, "courses"."active" AS t1_r11, "courses"."created_at" AS t1_r12, "courses"."updated_at" AS t1_r13, "courses"."category" AS t1_r14, "courses"."expired" AS t1_r15, "courses"."price" AS t1_r16, "courses"."cancelled" AS t1_r17, "courses"."notes" AS t1_r18, "courses"."url" AS t1_r19, "courses"."course_type_id" AS t1_r20 FROM "course_types" LEFT OUTER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."course_type_id" = "course_types"."id" WHERE (NOT (title LIKE '%Test%')) AND "courses"."active" = $1 AND "courses"."expired" = $2 AND "courses"."cancelled" = $3  ORDER BY "course_types"."order" ASC  [["active", "t"], ["expired", "f"], ["cancelled", "f"]]

In case it's important, I'm using `rails v 4.2.7`.

Comment: Can you please post the SQL generated and/or executed?

Comment: I've added the queries @SimoneCarletti

Comment: I see `WHERE (NOT (title LIKE '%Test%')) AND "courses"."active" = $1 AND "courses"."expired" = $2` in both examples